# How to set up DB2 10.5 programming environment for XA transaction manager?

Tags: c, db2, db2-luw, xa

I want to use DB2 10.5 on Linux for XA transactions. Does DB2 include a XA transaction manager?
How can I setup my C application for a XA transaction environment?

Comment: Please try to find some solution/tutorial/example. Do google. And post question with some analysis. Otherwise it is too broad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DB2 LUW 10.5 supports XA transaction managers](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.2pc.doc/doc/c0005106.html), but does not include one. If you want to work with one, [programming in C is supported](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.2pc.doc/doc/c0005107.html).

Comment: Thanks, for your reply